# Доступ к полям базового класса при наследовании

Tags: c++, наследование

```
class Discount
{
private:
    std::string nameCompany;
    size_t discount;
public:
    Discount() = default;
    ~Discount() = default;
    
    std::string getNameCompany() const { return nameCompany; }
    size_t getDiscount() const { return discount; }
    
    void setNameCompany(std::string const nameCompany) { this->nameCompany = nameCompany; }
    void setDiscount(size_t const discount) { this->discount = discount; }
    
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Discount&);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Discount&);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Discount& discount)
{
    in >> discount.nameCompany >> discount.discount;
    return in;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Discount& discount)
{
    out << "Name company: " << discount.nameCompany << " Discount: " << discount.discount;
    return out;
}


class Advertiser: public Discount
{
private:
    std::string nameProduct;
public:
    Advertiser() = default;
    ~Advertiser() = default;
    
    std::string getNameProduct() const { return nameProduct; }
    
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Advertiser&);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Advertiser&);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Advertiser& advertiser)
{
    in >> **?????**;
    return in;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Advertiser& advertiser)
{
    out << "Name company: " << advertiser.getNameCompany() << " Name product: " << advertiser.getNameProduct() << " Discount: " << advertiser.getDiscount();
    return out;
}
```

Каким образом можно обратиться к приватным полям базового класса из производного (для `operator>>`)?

Знаю что можно использовать модификатор доступа `protected` для полей базового класса, но возможно еще имеются варианты

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете преобразовать `advertiser` в ссылку базового класса в операторе ввода производного класса. Например:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Advertiser& advertiser)
{
    in >> static_cast<Discount&>(advertiser);     // Ввод части базового класса
    in >> advertiser.nameProduct;                 // Ввод части производного класса
    return in;
}
```